Overwrote data on VPS Drive
I have a VPS 16 cores, 34 GB RAM and 2.5TB disk.
I misread the webui and instead of inserting my Ubuntu 5 GB ISO into the virtual CD drive, the system copied the files to the disk. Now the drive is empty, except the contents of the iso of course. Since the process was too fast, I can't imagine that the 2.5TB were formatted. Currently, gparted is running with disk recovery. However, I  read that this can take a long time.
Any other suggestions to get the data back? I did read something about testdisk, but I know nothing about this tool.
Thanks a lot for any help!

What kind of data do you need to recover? Database files? Images and videos? And you can use testdisk for this kind of recovery. Best is to create a disk image and try different recovery software on it.

welcome, restore from backup. if you had no backup, then sorry but it's against Business environment Best Practices

Your data on the disk that was imaged over is lost.
The entire 2 TB block device does not need to be zeroed to make recovery difficult. It was formatted, by being replaced by a different file system image. Likely this heavily damaged the file system where it overlapped the ISO.  Any remainder of large unpartitioned space now has no protection of being used by some other file system or discarded (fstrim)  causing further corruption.
Bad analogy: imagine a library with a very large number of books. Then the entire catalog was lost and replaced with a different library's index. And titles from both are crammed into the same physical space. Sorting this out would be extremely tedious, the usual assumptions of where things are cannot be trusted.
Start recovery assuming you will not get this back.

Image a copy of the broken block device, in case you wish to attempt to piece it together later.
Restore data from any backups you have.
If the restore point is too old, work with whomever owns the application on what can be rebuilt.
The file system may need to be recreated.
If this broke the root file system, you may need to reinstall the operating system.

Should you wish to attempt recovery of the overwritten file system, do so on a copy. Incorrect assumptions about partitions or file system can make corruption much worse. I cannot guide you on specifics even if you had provided file system details, you should not trust me with your data. Perhaps hire a professional data recovery service. If doing it yourself, testdisk has various examples  online, as its a libre tool for this kind of thing. Consider carefully what the file system was, not what overwrote it.
